# Looping up inheritance to get overridden properties

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, properties

Consider the following classes

```
public class Super
{
    public abstract string Foo { get; }
}

public class Base : Super
{
    public override string Foo { get { return "Foo"; } }
}

public class Sub : Base
{
    public override string Foo { get { return "Bar"; } }
}
```

How can I, knowing the Type of Sub and with the PropertyInfo of Foo, loop through both declarations of Foo to invoke PropertInfo.GetValue(this) and therefore get both unique strings

Comment: Sub should be changed to Sub : Base and the property in Base should be virtual.

Comment: Ok, my bad, edited. But you get the idea?

Comment: You can use the keyword "new" to hide parent behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public class baseType
{
    public string P { get { return "A"; }}
}

public class child : baseType
{
    new public string P { get { return "B"; }}
}

public static object GetBasePropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}

public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}

void Main()
{
    var x = GetPropValue(new child(), "P");
    var y = GetBasePropValue(new child(), "P");
}
```

you should be able to build a method to do what you want using this methodology.

Comment: That will work, but that not his question.. 
For his question the answer will be NO, as there  is no way to call an overridden base method after the virtual method call.
I see that he accepted the answer anyway:)

Comment: Great, but why do you think `new public string P` works and `override public string P` doesnt???

Comment: I ran a test using the abstract override code above.  It did not work, so it looks like you wouldn't be able to do abstract and override.  Which makes since, you are overriding whereas with new you are simply hiding.